# Select syntax inside WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I use `SELECT` syntax inside `WHERE` for example I have following code:

```
SELECT 
    blah...blah..
    ...
WHERE  
(
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationName = 'instance: tomcat6_noram (SNMP)') AND 
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ComponentName = 'Memory Heap Used (B)') AND 
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.StatisticData >= 1908932600)
)
```

Here I am comparing values if its greater than or equal to `1908932600`. I want to use `SELECT` in place of `1908932600` so it will automatically compare values rather than statically code in query.

Comment: Will that `SELECT` still return only one result?. If you expect more results then you need another way to do it (either a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS`)

Comment: You are right, I will make it single value return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery, you just need parentheses around it:

```
APM_AlertsAndReportsData.StatisticData >= (SELECT ... FROM ...)
```

Note that it may run slowly depending on what you are doing in your subquery. It might be better to use a JOIN instead.

Comment: is top 1 required in sql server? i thought you got an error other wise. (as in even if you know it will only return one result) or is that just for assignment to variables

Comment: cool.. should have just tried it ;-) even this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2c6f/2

Comment: This is perfect! It works for me. I use they way it return only single value.

Answer (score 3):

You need a "correlated subquery" in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE  
(
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationName = 'instance: tomcat6_noram (SNMP)') AND 
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ComponentName = 'Memory Heap Used (B)') AND 
  (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.StatisticData >= (SELECT SomeValue FROM SomeTable))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple one:

Single value subquery

```
select * from Table1
where id = (select id from Table2 where Name = 'cool')
```

Muti Value subquery

```
select * from Table1
where id IN (select id from Table2 where Name LIKE 'A%')

select * from Table1
where id NOT IN (select id from Table2 where Name LIKE 'A%')
```

Corralated subquery

```
select * from Table1
where exists (select 1 from Table2 where Table1.id = Table2.id)
```